# Is there an easy way to set up Android to only update screen when it needs to?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-canvas, cpu-usage

I am making a board game. The board doesn't ever move, but pieces on top of it sometimes do depending on user interaction. There are also UI elements which may update periodically.

Right now the way I set it up is by overwriting the `onDraw()` method of a `SurfaceView` subclass. I have a drawing thread that constantly calls `postInvalidate()` in a while loop:

```
class PanelThread extends Thread
{
        //...
    long sleepTime = 0;
    long nextGameTick = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run)
        { // When setRunning(false) occurs, _run is
            c = null; // set to false and loop ends, stopping thread
            try
            {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder)
                {
                    // Insert methods to modify positions of items in onDraw()
                    _panel.postInvalidate();
                }
            } finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
            nextGameTick += MILLISECONDS_PER_FRAME;
        sleepTime = nextGameTick - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(sleepTime >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(sleepTime, 0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //we're behind, oh well.
            System.out.println("behind!");
            nextGameTick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

This is not efficient and is taking a lot of CPU. Is there a easy way to get android to only update when something changes?

Comment: Have You checked Android Pro Games for examples of games loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it needs a bit of refinement.

You definitely do **not** want to loop as fast as the CPU can handle it though. 
You should be sleeping your Thread in every loop for a little while. You most certainly do not need to do everything in your loop every millisecond.

I found this [guide to FPS control](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) to be incredible helpful in designing a game loop.

This [Android-specific game loop guide](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-game-loop.html) also provides a lot of great sample code and an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Ah of course totally neglected to actually control the FPS. Blame that on sloppiness. Thanks!